# accessing resource managers in lifecycle callback methods of a CMT SFSB

Tags: java, ejb

In section 4.6.1 of EJB 3.1 spec in table 2 one can find that it is possible to access resource managers from within lifecycle callback methods of a CMT SFSB. However from the same section:

> Accessing resource managers and enterprise beans is disallowed in the
>   session bean methods for which the container does not have a
>   meaningful transaction context and/or client security context.

According to section 4.3.15 PostConstruct method of a SFSB is such a method:

> A session bean’s newInstance, setSessionContext, other dependency
>   injection methods, life cycle callback interceptor methods, and
>   afterCompletion methods are called with an unspecified transaction
>   context.
>
> For example, it would be wrong to perform database operations within a
>   stateful session bean’s Post-Construct or PreDestroy lifecycle
>   callback interceptor methods and to assume that the operations are
>   part of the client’s transaction.

So my question is: what is the truth?